# Fast looping through a data frame with an if statement

Tags: r

I have a quite simple but relatively large data frame that looks somewhat like this:

```
vec1 <- rbinom(350000, 1, 0.1)
vec2 <- rep(NA, length(vec1))
df <- data.frame(vec1, vec2)
```

I need to assign `"not available"` or `"free"` in the second column, depending on if there is a `0` or `1` in the first column of the respective line.

This can be done via loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df[i,1] == 0) {
    data1[i,2] <- "not available"
  } else {
    data1[i,2] <- "free"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it takes quite a while this way. I am sure there must be quicker ways to achieve this.
Anybody with a hint?

Comment: This is a classic example of the adage "If I'm writing R code and thinking of using a loop, there's almost certainly a better way to do it...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifelse`

```
transform(df, vec2 = ifelse(vec1==0, "not available", "free"))
```

or

```
transform(df, vec2 = c("free","not available")[(vec1==0)+1])
```